# Open a file at a certain position and read one byte in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, files, output

Since two persons already voted to close this post, I'll try to make the question as clear as possible. A file on a physical device is represented as a binary sequence. That being said, what I need to do is to check the differences between the representations of two files at a such level (i.e. I need to compare the differences between multiple bytes on the same position across two different files), and to output such differences in a `bash` script.

Example:

```
file1: 00000000 01010101 10101010 11001100 00110011

file2: 00000000 01010101 01010101 00110011 00110011
```

The script should output:

```
differences: Byte 3 (file 1: 01010101; file2 10101010), Byte 4 (file1: 11001100; file 2: 00110011)
```

Or something along these lines.

So the first thing I need to do in order to accomplish this is to be at least able to open a file at a certain position and to read one byte and to output/store such byte. I could write a `C` program to do that, but **is there a way to do this within `bash`**?

Comment: Do you mean like [`cmp(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/cmp.1.html)? Otherwise I don't understand, what you want.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Let `00000000 01010101 10101010 ...` be the binary representation of a file; I need to extract some bytes in the position I want: for example I should be able to extract `01010101` with something like `var=$(getbyte 2 file)`; but since I need to use this to compare and output the differences between two files, the `cmp` solution below works perfectly for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `cmp`. It will compare two files byte by byte.

From [`man cmp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/cmp.1.html):

```
cmp - compare two files byte by byte
```

Although the number of lines must be equals on two files. Also note that `cmp` will point to the first difference only, to point to the next differences you can skip specific bytes from the start.

```bsh
$ cat foo 
this is
a test
$ cat bar
this
is a test
$ cmp foo bar 
foo bar differ: byte 5, line 1
$ cmp -b foo bar 
foo bar differ: byte 5, line 1 is  40    12 ^J
```

To print the differing byte values use `cmp -l`, from `man cmp`:

```
   -l, --verbose
          output byte numbers and differing byte values
```

Comment: `cmp` is actually what I'm using to spot the differences, but I rather need to output the offending byte's value

Comment: @kos: check my edits

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Now I'll have to sort out a way to parse that output!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `vimdiff`:

```
vimdiff -b file1 file2
```

[image]

Comment: This is very useful. Upvoted, but I need to sort out a way to manipulate the differences within `bash`